# How to `control background elements` in Website / WordPress?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I am customising a website in WordPress(CMS). I want to add some elements in my website as background design.

It look something similar like this:

[image: example-1[1]]

I google and found a way to do it - Using a builder tool in CMS - `Elementor`.

The good thing is, in `Elementor` there is a way to add `background-img` and control `background-position`.

The bad thing is, I have successfully added and control the element moving around until the place that I want. But The background element seems cannot cross the `<section>` which mean they will only stay in their own container.

[image: example-3]

I figured it out another way to do it, which is add the `<img>` at the current page. Then use `position: absolute` to position it properly.

But I prefer not to do that way.

Example snippet:

```css
#section-1 {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
}
  
#section-2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  background-image: url(https://temp1.asign.pro/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/element-2.png);
  background-position: -150px -223px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  color: black;
   padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<section class="section" id="section-1"></section>
<section class="section" id="section-2"></section>
```

Comment: Do you mind sharing the markup and CSS? If it's WordPress then you catch get it from dev tools (inspect element)

Comment: Hi @Nimsrules, thanks for your help! Not a problem. Just go to this link will do. https://temp1.asign.pro/. The markup and css too complex for me.

Comment: You should share your code here, so people can review and return you some advice

Comment: @LuuHoangBac Alright. Nice advice! Let me try to copy and extract the code.

Comment: I have added the working example. @Nimsrules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with using the triangles as a background-image is that you'll never be able to position them 'out' of the section. The background is a part of the element and can only go as far as the element's dimensions. However, you can make use of the pseudo element and position them absolutely, like so:

```css
#section-1 {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: visible;
}
  
#section-2 {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  color: black;
  padding: 20px;
  overflow: visible;
  position: relative;
}

#section-2::before{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: -70px;
  left: 0;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: url(https://temp1.asign.pro/wp-content/uploads/2019/05/element-2.png) no-repeat center center/100%
}
```

```html
<section class="section" id="section-1"></section>
<section class="section" id="section-2"></section>
```

Comment: Additionally, I've converted the multiple `background` properties in a shorthand